# Array adds the same character repeatedly?

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

Im trying to print out a grid of dots and Xs that are read from a text file, but for some reason it just takes one of the dots and adds it to the array repeatedly over and over again, instead of reading each individual character and adding that to the array at its respective location. How do i go about fixing this?

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Created a scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // Takes file name to find file
        Scanner inputFromFile = new Scanner(file);
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file); // reads file
        int r;
        while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) { // goes through each character in
                                                // file, char by char
            char c = (char) r;
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 75 ; y++) { // Adds file values to Array
                    GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
                }
            }
        }
        // Prints the initial environment
        System.out.println("Initial set: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++)
            System.out.println(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
    }
}
```

GameOfLife:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class GameOfLife {

static final int m = 25; // number of rows
static final int n = 75; // number of columns 
static char[][] grid = new char [m][n]; // Creates an empty (no dots or X's)grid of rows and columns. 

}
```

For Example:

Expected output:
[image: Expected output]

[image: Actual output]

Comment: Your for-loop is inside your while therefore you loop through `grid` and override all its values with the character you're reading each time your read 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this block

```
    while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) { // goes through each character in
                                            // file, char by char
        char c = (char) r;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 75 ; y++) { // Adds file values to Array
                GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
            }
        }
    }
```

Each time you read a character, it will go through and overwrite every cell with that character, meaning it will only contain whatever character is read last.

If you want to keep track of your coordinates as you read, remove the for-loops like such

```
    int y = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) { // goes through each character in
                                            // file, char by char
        char c = (char) r;
        GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
        y++;
        if (y == 75)
        {
            y = 0;
            ++i;
            if (i == 25)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do i go about replacing the initialized values of  i and y?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

That central `for` loop is the problem.  As mentioned you store each character read in every position in the 2D array.  You could implement it this way also:

```
    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file); // reads file
    int r;                                                 // file, char by char
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 75 ; y++) { // Adds file values to Array
            r = fileInput.read()) != -1; // goes through each character in
            if( r == -1 ) break;
            char c = (char) r;
            GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
        }
    }
```

Which is better, I'm not sure.  This way retains the familiar structure of a nested loop with the array, but it could exit early if the file input ends, which might cause bugs if the input does in fact end unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You are populating the entire array with each character because you've nested your loops. I think you should initialize your `grid` to `'.'` (since that appears to be empty).

There doesn't need to be a seperate class to contain your array, I'd make it a local variable unless you intend to move more functionality into it (but then everything shouldn't be `static`). I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to avoid leaking file handles. Next, I'd use the `Scanner` to read the file one line at a time (skipping empty lines and invalid characters). And, you can use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) to print your `grid`. Something like

```
final int m = 25;
final int n = 75;
char[][] grid = new char[m][n];
for (char[] arr : grid) { // <-- start with an empty grid.
    Arrays.fill(arr, '.');
}
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
File file = new File(input.nextLine());
try (Scanner inputFromFile = new Scanner(file)) {
    int row = 0;
    while (inputFromFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputFromFile.nextLine().trim();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char ch = i < line.length() ? line.charAt(i) : ' ';
            if (ch != '.' && ch != 'x') {
                continue;
            }
            grid[row][i] = ch;
        }
        row++;
    }
    // Prints the initial environment
    System.out.println("Initial set: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```